# HTML make the table column take the minimum space

Tags: html, css

I need the last column of my table to be as tiny as possible. How would I do that?

**Update:**

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Y7q6R/

Plot twist: I do not know what exact length will the string "Select all" have in different server-side translations.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Since</td>
    <td>Till</td>
    <td>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox">
            Select all
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: In according with it's text content of course

Comment: What have you tried ? Show your code and create a fiddle. People are more likely to help you if you help them understand the problem better.

Comment: Give the last column a class, then you can specify whatever size you want.

Comment: Hide it - if its invisible it doesn't take any space :-)

Comment: @scythargon Try explaining your question in more detail, currently the question you have asked has been answered correctly in the top post and in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

```
table td:last-child {
  /* change css padding, margin, width, height here */
}
```

This selects the `last-child` of the parent element.

http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/dp3vv/

I have changed the css properties of the last element (only background-color) you can alter those properties as per your needs.

If you're gonna get the result dynamically, then you're required to make the change dynamically by using jQuery, however you don't need to be doing that. So here is a quick one

```
table td:last-child {
   min-width: /* some val in % */
   max-width: /* some val in % */
}
```

Otherwise, please shift to jQuery to change the stuff dynamically depending on the `table`'s width and browser `window`'s current resolution.